# How to get data from database without looping?

Tags: laravel

In my controller function there is a foreach loop having query builder to get data from the database and after ending foreach loop, data is passed into views. This is looping more than 90 times.

```
class HomeController extends Controller {

public $menu;
public $msg;

public function __construct() {

    $this->isEditor();

    $this->menu = Config::get('constants.news.menu');

    $this->msg = Config::get('constants.news');
}

public function index(Request $request) {
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
    //dd(session()->all());
    $sessval  = session()->all();
    $uroles = DB::table('users_roles')
            ->where('id', Auth::user()->id)
            ->where('role_id','4')
            //->toSql();
            ->get();
    foreach($uroles as $key => $value)
    {
        $urole[]=$value->col-name;
        $companiesid[]=$value->col-name2;
        $rpending=DB::table('')
            ->select('')
            ->where('')
            ->where('')
            ->whereRaw("")
            ->count();
        $abc+=$rpending;

        $cactivities=DB::table('')
            ->select('')
            ->where('','=','')
            ->where('','=',$value->)
            ->where('','=',$value->)
            ->count();
        $def+=$cactivities;


        $pactivities=DB::table('')
            ->select('')
            ->where('','=','0')
            ->where('','=',$value->)
            ->where('','=',$value->)
            ->count();
        $mno+=$pactivities;


        $uactivities=DB::table('')
            ->select('')
            ->where('','=','0')
            ->where('','=',$value->)
            ->where('','=',$value->)
            ->whereBetween('due_date', [$tfrom, $to])
            ->count();

        $ghi+=$uactivities;


        $delayed=DB::table('')
            ->select('')
            ->where('','=','1')
            ->where('','=',$value->)
            ->where('','=',$value->)
            ->whereRaw('`actual_date`>`due_date` ')
            //->toSql();
            ->count();
        $jkl+=$delayed;
    }


    return view('view.name', compact('abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno'));
}
```

Any possible way to fetching the data in the background and when user loggedin it will render the view faster. Also i need to pass more data to the same view and that data is also getting from the database using forloop. How to reduce the loading time?. Please suggest any alternative way.

```
In view-

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
        <!-- small box -->
        <div class="small-box bg-green" style="background:green !important">
            <div class="inner">
                <h3>{{ $abc}}</h3>
                <p>Comp</p>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
                <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ./col -->
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
        <!-- small box -->
        <div class="small-box bg-orange" style="background: darkorange !important">
            <div class="inner">
                <h3>{{ $def}}</h3>
                <p>Delayed</p>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
                <i class="fa fa-book"></i>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fa fa- 
     arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ./col -->
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
        <!-- small box -->
        <div class="small-box bg-red"style="background: red !important">
            <div class="inner">
                <h3>{{ $ghi}}</h3>
                <p>Pen</p>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
                <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ./col -->
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
        <!-- small box -->
        <div class="small-box bg-aqua">
            <div class="inner">
                <h3>{{ $jkl}}</h3>
                <p>Pending</p>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
                <i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fa fa- 
     arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ./col -->
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the code of your view?

Comment: use ajax you cant use views like that

Comment: All the passed variable is number(in Lakhs') i.e abc= 2lakh Something

Comment: Can you please tell me how to call ajax to get data from the database when user is logged in

Comment: I think you should use `laravel relationship` if you want to get the data of eacher user..

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is with inefficient database queries. Querying within a loop usually results in poor performance.

A better approach would be to fetch all related data to user roles using SQL Joins or Eloquent Relationships.

Comment: which one is faster, Join or Eloquent Relationship??

Comment: @HidayatRiva'i fetching data with Eloquent Relationship behind the scenes performs SQL Joins (depends on type of a relationship between models). Most probably you won't notice any difference in performance on microscale, so it's better to create Models for your tables and access data via model relationships. This way code would cleaner and more maintainable.